# Is there a way to retrieve an NSPersistentStore knowing its URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspersistentstore

Is there a way to retrieve an NSPersistentStore knowing its URL?

Something like:

```
NSURL *url = @"aaa\bbbb\ccc\xyz.sqlite"

NSPersistenStore *ps =[NSPersistentStore persistentStoreFromURL: url];

[self DoSomethingWith: ps];
```

** Obviously the method 'persistentStoreFromURL' doesn't exist!

**Extra infos**:

I know this store is loaded in some Coordinator (I don't know which one) and I have to remove it from its coordinator before migrating its data to another store. I only know the URL for this store.

I am using several coordinators at the same time. I want to avoid to loop through them and then loop again through all theirs stores to check if the store.URL is equal to url. This is the reason I am asking if it is possible to get the store directly from its url and then get its coordinator wihout all the looping.

Comment: why do you not know the coordinator? You should have access to it?

Comment: I am using several coordinators at the same time. I wanted to avoid to loop through them and then loop through all theirs stores to check if the store.URL is equal to url. I was wondering if it is possible to get the store directly from its url and then get its coordinator wihout all the looping

Comment: What is your reservation for looping through them? The "store" is essentially just a file, document or in memory allocation. Without the coordinator there is no NSPersistentStore. If you only have the URL to the file, then you have no way of knowing where it is being used. The file only becomes a NSPersistentStore in the context of the coordinator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current store from the Persistent Store Coordinator with:

```
    NSURL *url = @"aaa\bbbb\ccc\xyz.sqlite"
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *yourPSC = self.psc // Create or obtain reference to your psc

    NSPersistentStore *ps = [yourPSC persistentStoreForURL:url];

    [self DoSomethingWith: ps];
```

If you do not know which of your psc contain the store at url, check `yourPSC.persistentStores` for contains a store with same url.

Like so:

```
   for (NSPersistentStore *store in yourPSC.persistentStores) {
       if ([store.URL isEqual:url]) {
           [yourPSC removePersistentStore:store error:nil];
       }
   }
```

Comment: See added extra infos

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize a `NSPersistentStore`using the designated initializer

```
initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:configurationName:URL:options:
```

as described in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSPersistentStore_Class/NSPersistentStore.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStore/initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator%3aconfigurationName%3aURL%3aoptions%3a)

You will also need a store coordinator for this.

If you want to remove a store from a coordinator, though, you will need to have access to the coordinator, otherwise there is no way of removing it. You can ask the `NSPersistentStore`for its `persistentStoreCoordinator` though. Migration of stores is also supported, depending on what you actually want to achieve. Note that a migration to another store might cause UI problems.

If you only have an URL you will need to ask a coordinator if it is assigned to the store. I see no other way out of the box.

Comment: See added extra infos